# how can i populate my list box from mysql table and build a basic search engine?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter, listboxitem

```
I am building a basic search function with autofill part of an entryform in tkinter where the user inserts prescription details in a database. The user types the name of medicine and in a entry box and then the user is given choices of the medicine he wants to insert in the database table f.e

User Entry: Insulin

Listbox: Insulin a
         insulin b
         insulin c etc.

I am fetching from my table in the database the values and puting them in a python list but when i try to populate the listbox with the items from the list ONLY the first item is being displayed besides the fact that when i print to check  my list all the items are displayed in my terminal
```

i have tried to populate the listbox directly from the table (the result of fetchall() ) and it is working i can see all the values from my db in the listbox  but i am unable to make the search function to work no matter how i change the for loop (im suspecting that thats where my mistake is) i chose to populate a python list again the same result only the first item is in the list box in {{ }}

```
    ck.set_appearance_mode("Light")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
    ck.set_default_color_theme("green")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

    PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


    class entrywin(ck.CTk):
    

    WIDTH = 950
    HEIGHT = 700
    WIDTHIMG = 600
    HEIGHTIMG = 200
    medboxlist=[]

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        self.title("Prescription Manager 1.0.0")
        #self.iconbitmap('C:\Syfar Projects\logo.ico')
        self.geometry(f"{entrywin.WIDTH}x{entrywin.HEIGHT}")
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.exitcommand)  
        self.resizable(False,False)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frame_left = ck.CTkFrame(master=self,
                                                 width=180,
                                                 corner_radius=0)
        self.frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")

        self.frame_right = ck.CTkFrame(master=self)
        self.frame_right.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe", padx=20, pady=20)
    
    # ============ frame_left ============

        # configure grid layout (1x11)
        self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(0,)   # empty row with minsize as spacing
        self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(1,)  # empty row as spacing
        self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(2,)    # empty row with minsize as spacing
        self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(3,)  # empty row with minsize as spacing

        self.med_label = ck.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_right, 
                                    width=10,
                                    text ='Φάρμακο:',
                                    text_font=("Roboto Medium", -16))
        self.med_label.grid(row=8, column=0, pady=10 , padx=130 ,sticky="w")
        self.med_ent = ck.CTkEntry(master=self.frame_right,
                                                width=200,
                                                )
        self.med_ent.bind('<KeyRelease>',self.checkls)
        self.med_ent.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=210,pady=0, sticky="w")
        self.med_box= tk.Listbox(master=self.frame_right,
                                    height=5 )
        self.medbox=pr.cur.execute('SELECT Description FROM meds')
        
        self.medres=pr.cur.fetchall() #results items from database WORKInG
        self.medlist=[]
        self.medlist.append(self.medres)
        print (self.medlist) #when i print the items in the list the items show up in terminal as expected
        
                
        self.update(self.medlist) #function to populate listbox with items from self.medlist
       
        self.med_box.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',self.filent)
        self.med_box.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=210,sticky='w')


    def update(self,data): # it populates the list only with the first item in my list PROBLEM WHY??
        self.med_box.delete(0,tk.END)
        for items in self.medlist:
            self.med_box.insert(tk.END,items[0])

    def filent(self,event): # chosing the item with mouse it is passed in the entry box WORKING
        self.med_ent.delete(0,tk.END)
        self.med_ent.insert(0,self.med_box.get(ACTIVE))
 
    def checkls(self,event): # function to compare entry box and listbox if they match PROBLEM HWHY??
        self.typed=self.med_ent.get()
        if self.typed =='':
           self.data=self.medlist 
        else:
            self.data=[] # i am passing the data in a new list and comparing them in my update function 
            for item in self.medlist:
                if self.typed.lower() in item.lower():
                    self.data.append(item)

        self.update(self.data)











    def exitcommand(self, event=0):
        self.destroy()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main = entrywin()
        main.mainloop()
```

Can someone please help me correct the code? im suspectin the for loops are the problem and nomatter how many examples and how much i checked the python manual im unable to correct them

Comment: `self.medres` is already a 2D array, so `self.medlist` is a list with only one item: `self.medres`. Actually you can just pass `self.medres` to `self.update()`.

Comment: i did that but then my autofill function is not working ( self.checkls() ) when i pass self.medlist the autofill is working but it shows self.medres only ... i need the items of self.medres in the list thats why im suspecting my for loop syntax is wrong but no matter how many examples or manuals i have checked the syntax seems right

Comment: You need to use `self.medres` inside `checkls()` as well. Note that `item` is a tuple, so `item.lower()` is wrong. Do you mean `item[0].lower()`?

Comment: again i did that and it is not working .... i managed to pass the items from medres in medlist by using extend() instead of append i  think on that part im fine now only the autofill part ( checkls ) remains THANK YOU VERY MUCH by pointing my mistake failing to recognise im passing a 2d list you helped me